# Woocommerce stock quantity display no longer working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Since updating to the latest version of **WooCommerce**, the stock quantity display no longer works. Before in the variation description box we could paste

```
Stock Qty: [variation_stock id="15869"]
```

and the quantity would display under the product.

Since the update all information in the description box has disappeared. When we reinstate it, it doesn't take long for it to disappear again.

This is pretty disastrous considering we've got 1900 variations. Anyone know  idea how to fix this problem please?

Comment: Update your theme (it need to be compatible with it) and your plugins too… First check in woocommerce settings > Status for read warnings. Enable Wordpress debug to see if you get some error messages.. You are using a custom shortcode that is not an official one, so the problem comes from the code that enable that shortcode.

Comment: <div class="woocommerce-variation-description wc-catalog-visibility">
  <p>Stock Qty: 8</p>

Kashalo thanks for your reply - is this what you mean by short-code?

Comment: Thanks Loic - I've passed your advice on to the lad who looks after the website